# How to find first item in list that can be divided by n?

Tags: python, list

I have created a list of string using user input and a menu that has different options on what to do with the list. However, for one of the functions, I'm supposed to find the first item's length in the list that is divisible by 3. For example, if I have a list with the following ['Hi', 'Chicken', 'Fire','Zombie'], how would I get 'Chicken' as it is the first item that has a length that is divisible by 3?

Comment: Break it down. How would you do this with a pencil and paper, one step at a time?

Comment: There's three parts to this: getting the length of a menu item, determining whether a number is divisible by 3, and getting the first item in a list that matches some condition. Which of those parts are you stuck on?

Comment: This is only one part of one task which my mind couldn't comprehend.  No one is doing my homework, they're helping me understand a part that I couldn't wrap my mind around.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

'Chicken' has 7 letters, and 7 is not evenly divisible by 3.  If the answer you're looking for is `Chicken`, you may need to adjust the problem statement.

```
>>> next(item for item in ['Hi', 'Chicken', 'Fire','Zombie'] if len(item) % 3 == 0)
'Zombie'
```

Comment: You gave away the solution to his homework. You should have posted just your two sentences of prose as a comment.

Comment: It's not my job to visit karmic payback on people who might be cheating on their homework or use Socratic trickery to get them to learn against their will.  If they are cheating, it'll catch up to them at finals.  If not, I just helped unblock somebody with an honest question.  :)

Comment: Please don't write code for users if they don't provide their own. We're not here to do people's homework (or job) for them. We're here to help them _learn_ and providing code to blindly copy and paste doesn't help with that.